# Can we have a div having aria-role = main inside a div having aria-role = main

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Is this a valid scenario:

Code:

```
<html>
   <div role = "main">
      <div role = "main">
      </div>
   </div>
</html>
```

Having a role main inside a div having role main. Will it cause any problem or issues in screen readers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The HTML5 documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) says

> Authors **must not** include more than one main element in a **document**.

(the term "document" is important and has to be understood correctly, see below)

That being said:

> **will it cause any problem or issues in screen readers?**

Yes. It may cause problem as the `main` element is a *non-obtrusive alternative for "skip to main content" links*. So having two `main` nodes could lead to unspecified behavior.

***EDIT: about the ARIA documentation***

[The ARIA documentation says](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#main)

> Note: Because document and application elements can be nested in the DOM, they may have multiple main elements as DOM descendants, **assuming each of those is associated with different document nodes**, either by a DOM nesting (e.g., document within document) or by use of the aria-owns attribute.

As long as an HTML standard web page has only one `document` node (which is the default role for `body`), it then **MUST NOT** contain more than one `main` (or `role=main`) element. But you still may nest document nodes inside the `body` tag and have no more than one `main` element associated with each document.

Comment: When a page loads, screen reader users can use keyboard shortcuts to jump between landmark (e.g. using ARIA roles such as `main`, `navigation`, `complementary` etc..) blocks in the page – as @Adam indicated. When they land on the `main` element, they will know they have found the pages' main content. If you have more than one, then this can create confusion.

Comment: @sideshowbarker You should know that `main` elements include both the `main` tag or any custom tag with `role=main`, except that the latter is intended to be used when the former can't be used (i.e before HTML5)

Comment: @sideshowbarker There's absolutely no difference, for a screenreader, between a `main` element and `role=main` element. The two specs are consistent. And the "SHOULD mark no more" sentence is unambiguously followed by an important note saying *" they may have multiple main elements as DOM descendants, **assuming each of those is associated with different document nodes**"*. So they can have multiple `main` (or role=main, no matter) elements as long as they reference different documents which is what the HTML5 documentation says.

Comment: @Adam the document says Authors must not include the main element as a descendant of an article, aside, footer, header or nav element.

But as i asked, i am not talking about 2 mains in a document as parallel but can it have main as a descendant in main

Comment: @Labeo No except if the inner `main` is part of a nested document. `<div role="main"><div role="document"><div role="main">`

Answer (score 1):

The [docs are pretty clear on this](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#main) (note: *should*, not must)

> Within any document or application, the author SHOULD mark no more than one element with the main role.

Whether this will cause issues in screen readers probably varies.

The [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) is instructive here as well.

Edit: [update in the HTML 5.2 spec](https://w3c.github.io/html/grouping-content.html#example-27d2e212):

> There must not be more than one visible main element in a document. If greater than one main element is present in a document, all other instances must be hidden using §5.1 The hidden attribute.